# Creating database copy at home

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a internal database for an application, but this database is not online and cant be accessed remotely. I want to create a copy of that database at home so that I can query or work at home whenever I want. How would I do this??
Also how would I update the database of my home when changes occurs in the original database??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I dont know. How can I check??

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this is to take a dump of the remote database and restore the database daily on your local. You will need a little help from DBA in case you are not aware on how to take a dump. Also, your local changes will be lost. If you are OK with these two, then you can go for this solution.

Comment: I can get the complete backup of that database. I just want to create a replica of that application at home. No worries about local changes. How to do that??

Comment: Once you have the back up, you can restore on your local. DB backup can be used to restore database at completely new database.

Comment: Do I have to use any tool?

Comment: Which database do you have? Oracle /MySql/SqlServer or something else?

Comment: I think Oracle...Any way to confirm??
Actually what I do is that I query the database through iplus and send the result. But I can do that only when I have logged in one of their systems. What i want to do is that I want to create a replica of that database in my home so that I can query whenever I want, and update that database once in a month so that whatever changes are made by them can be updated in my database as well

Comment: Its best to redirect this request via a DBA on that machine. You wont be able to take a dump if you don't know which DB you are using, I am guessing you wont have admin access/ sys access on DB as well, which will be needed for this activity. Also, you need to consider installing the Database on your own machine. You will need a licence for that.

Comment: isn't  there any database tool through which I can do it?

Comment: No, back up and restore would need admin access via command line in oracle. I am not 100% sure, but I dont think you can do this via tool

Comment: I have the access, but I dont want to change anything. I was just thinking that through that backup if there is any tool in which I can replicate the database and query anything...